# Trigger on Update Firebird

Tags: sql, triggers, firebird

Whenever the field `sync` is updated without the flag being `YES` I need to set that field to `NULL`.

```
CREATE TRIGGER my_trigger FOR customers
AFTER UPDATE
as
BEGIN
if(new.sync <> 'YES')
  then new.sync = NULL;
end
```

But I keep receiving the error:

> Dynamic SQL Error SQL error code = -104 Unexpected end of command -
>   line 6, column 26

I believe **line 6** is `then new.sync = NULL`? I thought the problem might be the use of `;` but it's not, because if I remove it then it gives the same error but in the **line 7**.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Solved.**

Some code was missing but besides that also the logic. I needed to used `BEFORE` and not `AFTER`.

```
SET TERM !; 
CREATE TRIGGER my_trigger FOR customers 
BEFORE UPDATE 
POSITION 0 
AS BEGIN 
    IF(new.sync <> 'YES') THEN BEGIN 
        new.sync = NULL; 
    END
END;
```